# How can I get the temperature readings out of natural images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am struggling with performing the OCR on a large set of images using Matlab in order to get the temperature readings. I have performed pre-processing on all the images grayscaling them, then using MserRegions function that enables to create a mask and trace the contours of the regions of interest. The original and final images are shown below:
[image]
[image]

I am currently trying to perform another MserRegions detection on this newly processed image and I have managed to create bounding boxes around each number as shown below

[image]

However as not all the numbers are exactly the same size, It will not merge all the corresponding bounding boxes. All the images don't show these numbers in the same spot and so I cannot trace a region of interest for the OCR.

[image]

The resulting output using the built in ocr function in Matlab is "Eee". I tried using the option Characterset but it returns me empty string which is logical as it doesn't recognize any nymbers. I have attempted to train a model using OCRTraining in Matlab as well without any success.

The code is added below.

```
imagefiles = dir(fullfile(CuredImages, '*.jpg'))

% Construct the full file name
filename = fullfile(CuredImages, imagefiles(210).name);
% Read Image
I = imread(filename);
%I = imrotate(imread(filename),90);
imshow(I)

%MSERregions
[mserRegions, mserConnComp] = detectMSERFeatures(I, ... 
    "RegionAreaRange",[200 8000],"ThresholdDelta",4);

figure
imshow(I)
hold on
plot(mserRegions, "showPixelList", true,"showEllipses",false)
title("MSER regions")
hold off


mserStats = regionprops('table', mserConnComp,"BoundingBox",'Area', 'Eccentricity','PixelIdxList')

bboxes = vertcat(mserStats.BoundingBox);

% Convert from the [x y width height] bounding box format to the [xmin ymin
% xmax ymax] format for convenience.
xmin = bboxes(:,1);
ymin = bboxes(:,2);
xmax = xmin + bboxes(:,3) - 1;
ymax = ymin + bboxes(:,4) - 1;

% Expand the bounding boxes by a small amount.
expansionAmount = 0.05;
xmin = (1-expansionAmount) * xmin;
ymin = (1-expansionAmount) * ymin;
xmax = (1+expansionAmount) * xmax;
ymax = (1+expansionAmount) * ymax;

% Clip the bounding boxes to be within the image bounds
xmin = max(xmin, 1);
ymin = max(ymin, 1);
xmax = min(xmax, size(I,2));
ymax = min(ymax, size(I,1));

% Show the expanded bounding boxes
expandedBBoxes = [xmin ymin xmax-xmin+1 ymax-ymin+1];
IExpandedBBoxes = insertShape(I,"rectangle",expandedBBoxes,"LineWidth",3);

figure
imshow(IExpandedBBoxes)
title("Expanded Bounding Boxes Text")
Q

% Compute the overlap ratio
overlapRatio = bboxOverlapRatio(expandedBBoxes, expandedBBoxes);

% Set the overlap ratio between a bounding box and itself to zero to
% simplify the graph representation.
n = size(overlapRatio,1); 
overlapRatio(1:n+1:n^2) = 0;

% Create the graph
g = graph(overlapRatio);

% Find the connected text regions within the graph
componentIndices = conncomp(g);

% Merge the boxes based on the minimum and maximum dimensions.
xmin = accumarray(componentIndices', xmin, [], @min);
ymin = accumarray(componentIndices', ymin, [], @min);
xmax = accumarray(componentIndices', xmax, [], @max);
ymax = accumarray(componentIndices', ymax, [], @max);

% Compose the merged bounding boxes using the [x y width height] format.
textBBoxes = [xmin ymin xmax-xmin+1 ymax-ymin+1];


% Remove bounding boxes that only contain one text region
numRegionsInGroup = histcounts(componentIndices);
textBBoxes(numRegionsInGroup == 2, :) = [];

% Show the final text detection result.
ITextRegion = insertShape(I, "rectangle", textBBoxes,"LineWidth",3);

figure
imshow(ITextRegion)
title("Detected Text")

ocrtxt = ocr(I, textBBoxes);
[ocrtxt.Text]
```

Comment: Have you tried filling in the outlines? The OCR might work better with solid characters

Comment: agreed. even going near _outlines_ is a mistake. OCR *hates* outlines. don't even try to "fill" those outlines. don't even calculate outlines in the first place. if you're lucky, those mser features give you a proper tree of contours/CCs that you can fill correctly